# Issue with installing fonts in Ubuntu 18.04 server

Tags: 18.04

I have installed custom fonts on Ubuntu 18.04 server, but they are not recognized in Chrome.  There are four of them, and they are all .otf fonts.  This is not a desktop version of Ubuntu, it's a cloud server so it's all command line.

My installed fonts are located in `/home/$USER/.fonts`, but there is also a fonts folder at `/usr/local/share/fonts` and another one at `/usr/share/fonts/truetype` (for `.ttf` fonts).

One answer I read on Stack Exchange from 2010 said to place them in `/usr/local/share/fonts`, then rebuild the font cache using `fc-cache -f -v`.

So I'm confused.  Which folder should I put the fonts in before rebuilding the font cache?  And should I install both `.otf` and `.ttf` versions?

Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: The user has sudo privileges so it has access to all folders.  In that case, which folder should I use?  If I put them there, do I then rebuild the font cache as shown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use your fonts system wide, put them in `/usr/share/fonts` according to their type, like in your case, the directory is `opentype`. Here is what it looks like inside my fonts folder:

```
user@ubuntu:/usr/share/fonts$ l
 AppleGaramond-BoldItalic.ttf   'Lucida MAC Bold.pfm'
 AppleGaramond-Bold.ttf         'Lucida MAC.PFB'
 AppleGaramond-Italic.ttf       'Lucida MAC.pfm'
 AppleGaramond-LightItalic.ttf   LucidaMAC.ttf
 AppleGaramond-Light.ttf         lucon.ttf
 AppleGaramond.ttf               MACGRAND.PFB
 Aquabase.ttf                    MACGRAND.PFM
 cmap/                           opentype/
 cMap/                           svg/
 eot/                            truetype/
 LITHOGRL.TTF                    type1/
'Lucida Grande Bold.ttf'         woff/
'Lucida Grande.ttf'              X11/
'Lucida MAC Bold.PFB'
```

Just put `.ttf`s in `truetype` folder here, and `.otf`s in `opentype`. Then reload the cache (Note: copy into these folders with `sudo` too):

```
 $ sudo fc-cache -f -v
```

You most probably are using your server application with the `root` user, so you need to install them system-wide. And yes, everytime when you add new fonts, you should refresh font cache.

Comment: Good answer, but one question.  I'm using a user with sudo priviliges.  Should I use root instead (I can).  Also, what do you mean by install system-wide.  Will the instructions you show above do that by default, or is there something else?

Comment: When you put them under `~/.fonts`, it's being accessible only by your user. If you do like above, it's being system-wide. Let's say you are using an http server and the user `john` owns its process. if you install system-wide, every user can access those fonts, so `john` too. Thus, it can use those font in you server application.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I'm doing it now.

Comment: The font cache was installed successfully, but with a user that has sudo privileges . Now chrome responds with "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" and the name of the .otf font.  So I changed my @font-face to specify .ttf and same error message.  Is that because I didn't use root to install the fonts?

Comment: I think the issue is that I used a relative path in my @font-face code, but I need to use the full path.  I'll try that now .

Comment: No. installing with `sudo` makes same effect. Check your font family's name, it could be the issue and I suggest installing same files on your desktop system and trying to access them. Some websites provide different fonts for different systems. e. g. after I install a mac font, couple of websites started using that font instead of the default sans font in my Ubuntu desktop. And I installed them with the way above. Thus, your problem should be something else. I also suggest opening another question with more info on your errors.

Comment: Yes, it must be the configuration. I don't know the code but full path might help.

Comment: The full path does help, but the fonts there are named slightly differently from local (in the @font-face), so I changed their names to conform and now I'm rebuilding the font cache.  I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: Now I'm really puzzled.  The font-cache update was successful, and the font names match exactly, but I still get 404-not found from Chrome.

Comment: fc-list shows /usr/share/fonts/truetype/CamphorW01-Thin.ttf is installed, and that matches the name in my @font-face in the css.  Any ideas why Chrome still says it's not found?

Comment: I'm not a web developer, I don't have any experience with providing fonts from server to clients. If your issue is being resolved by installing those fonts on the client's PC, it means you have a problem with providing those fonts. But I really don't know these stuff. You should ask another question for people who are experienced to answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this.  I've gotten this far at least.  I can ask a question about @font-face on Stack Overflow.  Thanks again